# Show that the "algebra generated by a semi-algebra" is actually an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

We know that algebra F generated by semi-algebra A of a set X is the collection of subsets of X which can be written as finite disjoint union of sets from A. The question was to prove this is an algebra.

I was able to show all things except the property that it is closed under complements. Idea is clear to me as it seems I have to take union of many sets from A but I am not getting how to put it down on paper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me know if your definition of semi-algebra and algebra is different; but my definition is (from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Measure_Theory/Basic_Structures_And_Definitions/Semialgebras,_Algebras_and_%CF%83-algebras))

> $\mathcal{A}$ is a semi-algebra if:
>
> 1. $\varnothing$ and $X$ are in $\mathcal{A}$
> 2. $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite instersection
> 3. If $S \in \mathcal{A}$ then $S^c$ (the complement) is a finite disjoint union of sets in $\mathcal{A}$.

I understand that you defined $\mathcal{F}$ as the set of finite disjoint unions of sets from $\mathcal{A}$, and you showed that $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies all of the properties of an algebra, except that it remains to show closure under complement.

For this, consider an element $S \in \mathcal{F}$; we know
$$
S = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_k,
$$
where $S_i \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $i$, and these sets are disjoint. So, that gives us
$$
S^c = (S_1^c \cap S_2^c \cap \cdots \cap S_k^c) = \bigcap_i S_i^c.
$$
Well that isn't quite helpful, because the $S_i^c$ are not necessarily elements of $\mathcal{A}$ (since $\mathcal{A}$ isn't necessarily closed under complement). But we haven't used property (3) above of a semi-algebra -- this tells us each $S_i^c$ can be written as a finite disjoint union of sets in $\mathcal{A}$. So we get
that each $S_i^c$ can be written as $S_{i,1} \cup S_{i,2} \cup \cdots \cup S_{i,k_i}$, where this union is disjoint, and where $k_i$ depends on $i$, and where each $S_{i,j}$ is in the semi-algebra $\mathcal{A}$.
$$
S^c = \bigcap_{i=1}^k \bigcup_{j=1}^{k_i}S_{i,j}.
$$
To show $S^c$ is in fact in $\mathcal{F}$, we want to show that it's a disjoint union of sets from $\mathcal{A}$, and right now we have an intersection. So we should distribute the intersection inside the union to get a union (the notation gets a bit messy)
$$
S^c = \bigcup_{j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_k} \bigcap_{i=1}^k S_{i,j_i}, \tag{1}
$$
where that union is taken over all possible choices of $j_1$ to $j_k$ (try a small example if that is confusing.)

I claim that (1) is a disjoint union of elements in $\mathcal{A}$. It's clearly a union, and each element is an intersection of $S_{i,j_i}$ terms, which is in $\mathcal{A}$ since $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under intersection. So what remains for you to show is that any two terms $\cap_{i=1}^k S_{i,j_i}$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think the definition of a generated algebra from a semi-algebra is wrong. In a semi-algebra, the complement of a set needs to be a finite union of disjoint sets from A.

But the generated algebra by A takes all possible finite unions of elements of A (don't need to be disjoint) of elements in A.

With that, it is clear that what you end up with is an algebra.

To prove that it is closed under unions,

If x is in F and y is also in F, their union is a union of unions. ie, x is a union of sets in A and y is also a union of sets in A so together it is a finite union of sets in A.

To prove that it is closed under complementation,

There are many ways to do this as pointed out in another answer. But, the approach I will take is to first prove that it is closed under finite intersections. This is easy. Suppose x and y are in F. Then x is a union of elements in A and y is also a union of elements in A. The intersection of x and y is an intersection of two finite unions. Intersection distributes over unions and thus what you end up with is a finite union of intersections of elements in A. Each of those intersections is again an element of A because A is a semi-algebra. Thus, the intersection of x and y is again a union of elements in A.

Now take x to be an element in F. Then x is a union of elements in A. Thus, complement of x is an intersection of complements of elements in A (De Morgan). Each of those complements is a union of elements in A because A is a semi-algebra. Since each of those complements is a union of elements in A, each one of which is also in A. So now you have a finite intersection of elements in A and since A is closed under intersection of two elements, you can one by one reduce the finite intersection down to intersections of two elements and finally you end up with x as an element of F.

Last thing to show so that it is an algebra is the entire set X is also in F. (The definition of a semi-algebra I know just includes that the empty set is in A.)

But anyways, X is the complement of the empty set, thus it can be written by a finite disjoint union of elements of A. Thus, it can be written as finite union of elements of A which means it is in F.

One thing to show also is that it is also the smallest generated algebra. This is easy, Create an algebra on A, G. You can prove by induction that any finite union of elements in G is also in G. (An algebra is closed by any finite unions.) We also know that, A is a subset of G. Thus, for any element x in A, x is also in G. Finally, F which is all the possible finite unions of elements in A is a subset of G.