# A reference for a proof

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Following is from the book *Ergodic Theory of Numbers*
[image]
After lots of search I couldn't find neither the book KT66 nor a proof itself somewhere else. Does someone knows a reference for a proof?

Comment: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387948300

Comment: @JohnDouma you kidding, right?

Answer (score 2):

The class $\mathcal C$ is an algebra of sets. See [1].
Let $M$ be the    collection of sets $B$ that can be approximated by elements of
$\mathcal C$  (i.e. for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $C \in \mathcal C$
with $\mu (B \triangle C) <\epsilon$). Then $M$ contains $\mathcal C$. Also, it is easy to see that $M$ is a monotone class as defined in [2] : If $B_n$ in $M$ tend to $B$ monotonically, then $\mu(B_n \triangle B) ) =|\mu(B_n)-\mu(B)| \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ by continuity [3].   Thus for large $n$ we have $\mu (B_n \triangle B)<\epsilon/2$, so any $C \in \mathcal C$ that approximates $B_n$ within $\epsilon/2$, will approximate $B$ within $\epsilon$. Now the monotone class theorem [2] yields the conclusion: $M$ contains the $\sigma$-field generated by $\mathcal C$.

[1] [Show that the "algebra generated by a semi-algebra" is actually an algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146983/show-that-the-algebra-generated-by-a-semi-algebra-is-actually-an-algebra)

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem

[3] http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/E_2.html

Comment: I think I didn't understand your answer : You form M and the question is if M is nonempty. If M is nonempty then it's the theorem I need a proof of (?). But then you prove another thing not M being nonempty, am I right?

Comment: Also, even though I know Monotone class theorem, but I didn't understand your argument how you proved the theorem?

Comment: I added some detail, I hope it is clearer now. Certainly $M$ is nonempty, as it contains $\mathcal C$. The goal is to show that it contains the $\sigma$-field generated by $\mathcal C$. This follows from the monotone class theorem once we verify that $M$ is a monotone class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a book for that and as I guessed many pages I needed to learn to understand the final conclusion.